# Liferay 7: ADT custom for blog, how to get the post url

Tags: liferay-7

I've created a custom ADT for rendering blog posts. For each post I need the link "Read More". 
I watch the BlogEntry class but I didn't find any url for the specified post.

I'm working with Freemarker.

Thanks in advance

Luis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as curBlogEntry>

            <#assign 

                viewURL = renderResponse.createRenderURL()
            />      

            ${viewURL.setParameter("mvcRenderCommandName", "/blogs/view_entry")}
            ${viewURL.setParameter("redirect", currentURL)}
            ${viewURL.setParameter("urlTitle", curBlogEntry.getUrlTitle())}
            ${viewURL.setParameter("p_p_state", "maximized")}
           /* code */
           <a href="${viewURL}">Read More</a> 
    </#list>
 </#if>
```